# MSVC 2010 templated map in class crashing compiler

Tags: c++, class, templates, visual-c++, dictionary

Why does the following code crash the compiler?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class test{
public:
    template <typename T>
    std::map<std::string, T> stuff;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    test peanuts;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a bug in the compiler or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to have a templated variable, you can only have class templates or function templates.  If it's crashing the compiler, then *that* is a bug, but it is not valid C++.  You can do something like

```
    class test{
    public:
        template <typename T>
        class Map {
        public:
            std::map<std::string, T> stuff;
        };
    };
```

instead.